# Identifier "friends_name" is undefined & the Identifier "input " is undefined? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, input, undefined

I am trying to prompt the user to enter his or her first name.
I wrote "hello,first_name", where first_name is the name entered by the user.
Then I modified the code as follows: change the prompt to "enter the name of the person you want to write to" and change the output to "Hello, first_name,"following  do you like where you are right now in life (y/n)?";
this Is right before I wrote an if statement, letting the user make the decisions on what code to execute, but the input in my a given "conditions" isn't working because its undefined despite me putting assigning them to 'y' and 'n'.
Long story short I don't understand entirely to how to define the first_name and the input, I'm trying to have the user input those values to be assigned to those variables. 
[The Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft06i.png)

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "iostream"
 #include"string"
 using namespace std;

 int main()
     {
string first_name;
cout << " Please enter your first name (followed by 'enter'):\n";
cin >> first_name;
    cout << "Hello," << first_name << " do you like where you are right now in life (y/n)?:\n";
    cin >> first_name;
    if (input =='y') {
        cout << "what do you like about it over,the people?(y/n)";//?:\n"

    }
    else if (input == 'n') {
        cout << " what do you hate about it,the expenses?(y/n)"//?:\n"
    }
    else cout << "invalid choice";
    cout << " what was your friends name again ?" << endl;
    string = friends_name;
    cin >> friends_name;
}
return 0;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Where in the code do you define `friends_name`?  Maybe the `=` in `string = friends_name` is a typo?  See the line where you declare `first_name`.

Comment: that my main problem, I don't understand how I declare the first_name, when id like the user to input the value of the first_name. and yea the  that is a type I meant data type string followed by friends_name;

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Matthews, how do you write the friends_name, where the variable is declared and can be use for the user input?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews,  there is a problem with the last part of the code, the else cout << "invalid choice", it doesn't say invalid when I write any other response besides the y/n

Comment: When I try to compile your example, I get errors because `friends_name` is not defined.  Did you mean to use `string friends_name;` without the `'='`?

Comment: yea I did, my bad but what what about the "invalid choice" situation, it doesn't say invalid whenever the user type any other response besides the y/n. 
Even if the user answers the questions correctly, both the last question 
"what's your friends name" and the second question are asked simultaneously. 
And like before despite what the user types, the "invalid choice" does not pop up nor does the last statement.
Heres an image to show you what I mean about the last question and the second question. When you ran the code did you experience what I'm trying to delineate to you,@ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 12 of your program it looks like you've used the variable first_name instead of input. Replace "first_name" with "input". 
Eg:

```
cin>>input
```

Also as mentioned in the comments, make sure you declare all the variables that you use

Eg:

```
string first_name;
string input;
string friends_name;
```

Edited working code looks like:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "iostream"
 #include"string"
 using namespace std;

int main(){
 string first_name;
 string friends_name;
 string input;
 cout << " Please enter your first name (followed by 'enter'):\n";
 cin >> first_name;
 cout << "Hello," << first_name << " do you like where you are right now in life (y/n)?:\n";
 cin >> input;
 if (input =="y")
     cout << "what do you like about it over,the people?(y/n)";//?:\n"
 else if (input == "n")
    cout << " what do you hate about it,the expenses?(y/n)";//?:\n"
 else cout << "invalid choice";
 cout << " what was your friends name again ?" << endl;
 cin >> friends_name;
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The OP will also need to declare the variable `input`.

Comment: how do you declare the op(I'm assuming by op you mean the operators)for now I'm getting  this // no operator "==" matches these operands. what does that mean, @ThomasMatthews?

Comment: OP is short for original poster. Secondly, in your code, the opening and closing curly braces are way off (two extra in the main at the end, and the one before return 0 should be moved to after return 0).

Comment: Also, 
There are syntax errors in your code (missing semi colon in cout line for "input=='n'"). make sure you check for these

Comment: @AnkitPatnaik, youre amazing that cleared up everything.

Comment: @AnkitPatnaik, there is a problem with the last part of the code, the else cout << "invalid choice", it doesn't say invalid  when I write any other response besides the y/n

Comment: @ColinCruz It does for me. What does your output look like?
Mine looks like this: 
Please enter your first name (followed by 'enter'):
Hello,Ankit do you like where you are right now in life (y/n)?:
invalid choice
 what was your friends name again ?
Ankit